# Positive or negative Seebeck Coefficient?

Tags: thermocouple

Say I have a metal wire for a thermocouple, the cold end is 20C and the hot end is 500C. If I measured at the hot end of the wire with respect to its cold end and got a voltage of -3.6mV, would the Seebeck coefficient be positive or negative?

I have been going around in my head with this problem, so an explanation and answer would be appreciated.

Comment: IMO it can't be concluded without knowing what kind of leads you used to make the measurement.